# emacsclient always runs as console application

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

When emacs is not already running, emacsclient always starts as a console application, but I'd like it to start as a gui application.

This is the command I use:

```
emacsclient -a "" file
```

The `-a ""` is there to start an emacs instance, if none is running already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about specifying `-a /usr/bin/emacs` or whatever your emacs is?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Emacs frame:

```
emacsclient -c -a "" file
```

The advantage of `-a ""` compared to [@choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698935/4279) is that it starts emacs in a daemon mode so the next time you'll try to open a file it will open it almost instantly without requiring you to start Emacs with a server either manually or via `.emacs` with `(server-start)` or `(server-mode 1)`.

Comment: `-a ""` and `-a "emacs"` should have the same behaviour.

Comment: @jfsebastian what's the difference?

Comment: @daniel kullmann: with `-a ""` Emacs is started in daemon mode.